# How does mov eax store data in memory?

Tags: assembly, memory-management, nasm, masm, cpu-registers

I have the following assembly commands:

```
mov eax, 10001
mov [eax], DEADCODEh
```

What I know is

- I am talking about X86
- eax has 32 Bits
- I have to keep little endian in mind

So how does the memory look like?
Is the whole hex-number stored at 10001 or only a part of it?
Depending on that how do adresses 10002, 10003 and 10004 look like?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code does the following thing:

1. Load `eax` with the value 10001 (decimal). This is 0x2711 in hexadecimal. The value of `eax` is now 0x00002711. Note the leading zeros as eax is a 32 bit register.
2. Store the value 0xdeadc0de (note the 0, which you wrongly copy/pasted) into memory at the address contained in `eax`. Since the byte order is little endian, the memory around 10001 is going to have the following contents:

   ```
   10001: 0xde
   10002: 0xc0
   10003: 0xad
   10004: 0xde
   ```

Comment: Thanks very much. Now I am confused. I thought little endian means high adress value allocated to low digit value?